# jquery ajax jsonp post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, jsonp

I'm attempting to post form field results to a rest API located on another domain in the form of jsonp via ajax request.  While this DOES work and the api receives the data I'm sending, chrome's network is showing this request as get rather than post, and chrome's console is firing the error function rather than success.

consider:

-insert generic html form-

```
$("form#email_signup").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var optionID = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
        emailID = $('#emailsignup').val();

    $.ajax({
    url: 'rest api',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"type":"mergeListMembers","source":"signupForm","EMAIL_ADDRESS_":emailID, "GENDER":optionID, "EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_":"I"},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(){
          console.log('success!')
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error!')
        }
    });
    alert('Thanks for signing up!');
});
```

Am I understanding this correctly?  Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Myles

Comment: Does the chrome network tab show a status code returned from the rest API. Is it a 200, or 500?

Comment: Yes it does.  200 - OK.

Comment: In that case, there's no problem with the API. It's possible that the data is malformed and the browser cannot parse it, hence why the jQuery error function is returned. In the network tab, click on the ajax request, then copy the response into a JSON formatting tool, like JSON lint, which might highlight any errors.

Comment: Is there an explanation of the error returned. What happens when you log the textStatus and errorThrown variables?

Comment: The only explanation I can see is that the query is being treated as GET, which isn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you cannot use POST in cross-domain .
Change to GET

Comment: Using GET yields exactly the same results.. still fires the error!

Comment: Does your service return a json? (probably a parsing error)

Comment: The service doesn't accept GET requests (although it still seems to receive my data), it only accepts posts.  It returns a string.

Comment: You can change the service to accept post. And as far as i know jsonp expects to get a json in return and not text... 
I think you will have to change your service

Comment: The service already accepts post.  The issue here is that my post is being viewed as GET (in chrome).

Comment: It is viewed as GET because jsonp doesnt support POST... But again, it looks like your problem is the data parsing (should return json) and not the POST, but it might be connected.